# How is TikZ meant to be pronounced? "tiks", "tikz" or "tik-zee"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pronunciation

Disclaimer: I'm not sure this question is on topic on either the main site or the meta site, but the question itself is definitely "meta".

Knuth writes about the canonical pronunciation of *TeX* at the beginning of his TeXbook. But what about *[TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)*? How is it meant to be pronounced? Is there some canonical pronunciation for it?

I personally pronounce it "tiks", but all speakers in a podcast I listened to recently were pronouncing it "tik-zee". (Forgive me for not using the [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet); I'm no expert.)

Obviously, I'm not asking how *you*, in particular, pronounce it, but for an authoritative source about some canonical pronunciation of *TikZ*, if any exists.

Comment: It's a secret society: you are not supposed to know.

Comment: Since it's German (TikZ ist kein Zauberprogramme), you should use German pronunciation rules.

Comment: Yes, it's German, but it's not "Zauberprogramme" but "Zeichenprogramm": "TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm" which means "TikZ is not a drawing software". I usually say "Tiks".

Comment: @David Carlisle; Do you also not want to belong to any club that will accept people like you as a member?

Comment: First rule of TikZ: Don't speak about TikZ, ahmmm, the meaning of TikZ. ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it's so secret even the developers don't know (at least this one doesn't).

Comment: @MarkWibrow perhaps all the others know and they are just not telling you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though the functionality of TikZ is somewhat magical, the *Z* it is not referring to a *Zauberprogramm* (magic tool) but to a *Zeichenprogramm* (drawing tool).

The maintainers of TikZ are German and the meaning of "TikZ" is German so I would pronounce it as in German. I just looked up the IPA for my way of pronouncing it and it is the same as each first letter of the four words written in IPA. So I guess, I should be more or less right.

If you can't read IPA: I would describe the pronunciation as *tikts*.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
TikZ [tɪkʦ] ist [ɪst] kein [kaɪ̯n] Zeichenprogramm [ˈʦaɪ̯çn̩pʀoˈɡʀam]

\emph{TikZ ain't no drawing tool}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A [useful link](https://translate.google.com/#de/en/TikZ%20ist%20kein%20Zeichenprogramm) to listen the pronunciation...

Comment: The answer is consistent with the TikZ reference manual: section "Part III TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm" states that 'TikZ means "TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm."' --- this is just to provide the reference